# Ruby on Rails : conditional display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, conditional-statements

I have just started with Ruby on Rails and I have a use case where I need to map my Json response from a call back into an existing Ruby model. There are a few fields, however, that cannot be mapped directly. I have a resource class looking like this:

```
class SomeClassResource
  attr_reader :field

def initialize(attrs = {})
  @field = attrs['some_other_field']
end
```

I have then a method that if `some_other_field` matches to a specific string then return true, alternatively false, as follows:

```
  def some_method(value)
    value == 'aString' ? true : false
  end
```

I then need to display either true or false in my view. What is the correct approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should simplify your method to this:

```
# app/models/some_class_resource.rb
def some_method(value)
  value == 'aString'
end
```

Then to show it in a view you would want to get the value in a controller first (into an instance variable scoped to the view):

```
# app/controllers/some_class_resources_controller.rb
class SomeClassResourcesController << ApplicationController
  def show
    resource       = SomeClassResource.new
    @true_or_false = resource.some_value('aString')
  end
end
```

Then you'll want a view with something like this:

```
# app/views/some_class_resources/show.html.erb
<h1>My view</h1>
Was it true? <%= @true_or_false %>
```

You will also need the appropriate `show` route in your routes file.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :some_class_resources, only: [:show]
```

Comment: the only issue I have is that I do not have access to the json value in the controller itself, but rather in the service where I have a response from a get request and I map the json back into the model. Do you recommend to move ```@true_or_false``` there?

Comment: This means that ```aString'`` is coming from my JSON response and if I pass it in as per your example in the controller, I am kinda overwritting what the response is giving me back (tested)

Comment: Yes, if the JSON value comes from a service to the model, just have the model handle things and provide access to the value you're after for the view. So maybe a new method on the model. Or get fancy and wrap the model in a decorator object that provides this for the view. Either way, your instincts seem good.

Comment: It might be time to make a new question with your exact code (or simplified) and new goals.

Comment: just shared my current implementation if this can be of help. Thank you for this, appreaciated

Comment: you are absolututely right, apologies. I deleted the question and created this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74525038/ruby-on-rails-conditionally-display-a-dynamic-value-from-a-json-response